# C++: Alternative to std::map when all entries guaranteed to be unique

Tags: c++, std

I have a simple use case: parsing a header.  I have to parse very many of these headers, and I am guaranteed to have a header which does not repeat any fields.

As I parse these headers, I organize them in a `std::map`,

```
// pseudo code
std::map<std::string,std::string> x;
x[key] = value;

// etc.
```

I have streamlined my code, and the single slowest point is the map insertion for these headers. Specifically, the `std::_Rb_tree_iterator` interior method called when inserting items into the map.  Benchmarking with gprof indicates that this single method, when called **only** during the read-in of these headers (and not during any other operations that may insert or remove items from the map) takes approx. 50% of my runtime.

---

The question amounts to: supposing I can guarantee the uniqueness of all entries to the map, is there a way for me to disable the `std::_Rb_tree_iterator` for streamlined map insertion?

I would prefer to run the slow code than use something other than `std::map`, unless the replacement has an equivalent api (i.e., the iterators yield a `std::pair<std::string,std::string>`).

Comment: No, you can't disable the check.  You could try a different data structure though.  What happens if you use a `std::unordered_map` which has O(1) insertion.

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair</*const*/ std::string, std::string>>` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` inserts are slow because it tries to balance a binary search tree. Use `std::unordered_map` to use a hash table; while it will not keep the elements sorted, it will be a lot faster to insert elements, and it's highly recommended if you don't need the elements sorted.

Also, try inserting using `insert` calls; `[]` will first create an empty element, then write your own element over it.